# What GCE IPs should I open to Google Load Balancer on Firewall to my instance groups?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a `node.js` `instance group` being balanced by `google load balancer`. Instance group's IPs are ephemeral and the load balance IP is static.

Accordingly to [this google manual](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/cross-region-example#shut_off_https_access_from_everywhere_but_the_load_balancing_service), after everything is set and running, I should be able to replace the `0.0.0.0/0` firewall rule to this:

> gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-lb-and-healthcheck \
>       --source-ranges 130.211.0.0/22,35.191.0.0/16 \
>       --target-tags http-tag \
>       --allow tcp:80

But unfortunately, this didn't work and I got a `502`.

How can I find what IP I must allow in the firewall so Load Balancer can reach my `instance-group`? I tried my load balancer external IP and this also didn't work.

The only rule it seems to work is to open `0.0.0.0/0`.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the IP addresses for the health checks opened as well: `209.85.152.0/22`, `209.85.204.0/22`, and `35.191.0.0/16`. Without this the LB won't send traffic to a backend because it thinks it's unhealthy.

Docs: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks#health_check_source_ips_and_firewall_rules

Comment: I opened all these ports and so 0.0.0.0/0 and still not working. The instance group keeps restarting the instance all the time. Very difficult to find out what is happening.

Comment: @JLCDev if your instances are restarting, then you probably have Autohealing enabled on the instance group. This is a separate health check defined on the Instance Group, different from the one defined for the Load Balancer. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances#monitoring_groups

Comment: ZachB, we have configured the same HC for both services. I understand that Load Balancer don't have the power to drop an instance so only the instance group load balance could do it. We can reach the service in the instance from the browser.. crazy stuff. Are you aware of any detailed log we can investigate?

Comment: You might find something relevant in the log viewer if you select "GCE Instance Group Manager" (might say why instance was deleted) or "Cloud HTTP Load Balancer" (should show health check requests).

Comment: (And to slightly correct my earlier comment, I said "this is a separate health check ... different from the one defined for the LB" -- it could be the same health check for both, but they're selected in two different places.)